# Фоновая надпись на ComboBox c# Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Добрый день, подскажите как сделать фоновую надпись на ComboBox.
Пользователь должен иметь представление о том, что он увидит, когда бокс раскроется, как реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не мудрствуя лукаво, можно разместить `Label` рядом со стандартным `ComboBox` и в нём написать, что нужно.

Но, при желании, можно извратиться. Нужно послать сообщение [CB_SETCUEBANNER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb775897(v=vs.85).aspx) с помощью функции [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class WatermarkedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        const uint CB_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1703;

        base.OnHandleCreated(e);

        if (IsHandleCreated)
        {
            SendMessage(Handle, CB_SETCUEBANNER, IntPtr.Zero, "Watermark");
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wp, string lp);
}
```

Фоновая надпись (watermark) будет видна в комбобоксе, когда он не в фокусе и когда не выбрано ни одно значение в нём.