# Описание combobox c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно описать comboBox? Например, в описание combobBox написано ФРУКТЫ, а при клике в comboBox показывает название фруктов: яблоко, апельсин, банан, кокос и.т.д.

Comment: Поставить рядом с ним `Label` с текстом «ФРУКТЫ»? Или что-то другое имеется ввиду?

Comment: в самом comboBox должен быть. Например, Выбрать фрукт

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/548748/184217

Answer (score 2):

Простой вариант: использовать свойство [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
comboBox1.Text = "Выберите фрукт";
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Апельсин",
        "Груша",
        "Банан"});
```

Для того, чтобы вариант сработал нужно чтобы в [`DropDownStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) было установлено значение `DropDown` (значение по-умолчанию).

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте первым в списке название вашего `ComboBox`, Например `=== Фрукты ===`. И при инициализации формы просто указывайте стартовый индекс 0 для этого элемента. И пока пользователь не нажал на этот элемент ему будет отображаться данное поле. А для правильного выбора значения из списка в обработчик события ItemSelected добавьте игнорирование выбора строки с нулевым индексом, чтобы пользователь не смог щёлкнув по этой строке закрыть выпавший список с перечислением элементов. Это не так сложно. Просто откройте вкладку "события", что рядом с иконкой "свойств" элемента и найдите нужное вам событие. В итоге вы получите то, что желаете. И, не забудьте указать нужное значение в свойстве максимального размера элементов в выпадающем списке. А то получите список со скролом.

Пример моей реализации.

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _lastIndex;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Define first time state.
        _lastIndex = 0;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reset element state.
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        comboBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Skip action if tries select the label index.
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            return;

        _lastIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Restore previous index if new index is 0.
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = _lastIndex;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Требуется переменная конструктора.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

    /// <summary>
    /// Обязательный метод для поддержки конструктора - не изменяйте
    /// содержимое данного метода при помощи редактора кода.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // comboBox1
        // 
        this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "=========== Фрукты ===========",
        "Абрикос",
        "Ананас",
        "Апельсин",
        "Виноград",
        "Лимон",
        "Персик",
        "Яблоко"});
        this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
        this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(196, 21);
        this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        this.comboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted);
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(223, 10);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = " Reset";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(310, 49);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Example Form";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
```

Comment: Как то сложно, как мне кажется. В смысле, наверняка должен быть вариант попроще

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. У вас ещё впереди разочарование на фоне желаемого и суровой реальности от Microsoft в лице WinForms и C#. Если вам нужны более гибкие вещи, то создавайте собственный `Control` в виде кастомного `ComboBox`. Это будет куда сложнее, но гораздо эффектнее.

Comment: К счастью разочарование у меня далеко позади :) Я попробовал вариант от @default_locale, он прекрасно работает. Ваш вариант подойдет скорее всего не для комбобокса, а для дропдауна.

Comment: Так его вариант как раз для DropDown стиля элемента ComboBox.

Comment: Его вариант для `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`, ваш скорее для `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`

Comment: Вам следовало бы уточнить такое важное условие. Эти типы имеют разное отображение и свойства при взаимодействии с ними. Если не ошибаюсь, то DropDown можно скролить мышкой если он в фокусе. А вот с DropDowList только клики.

Comment: Я не автор вопроса, я просто мимо проходил :) Просто когда автор вопроса будет читать ответы, он поглядит какой вариант для какого стиля больше подходит и сам выберет. DropDown - это стиль а-ля комбобокс, где можно писать в поле поиска. DropDowList - это старый добрый дропдаун, где можно только выбрать элемент, писать никуда нельзя

Comment: я пробовал combobox.text="blablabla" не знаю почему не работает. Данные беру из базы данных и вывожу на комбобокс. Мне надо чтоб первый был информация для клиентов

Comment: `ComboBox` это массив строк. Вам нужно добавлять через `comboBox1.Items.Add("BlaBlaBla")`.

Comment: Хороший вариант, но пример кода был бы иллюстративнее, на мой взгляд :)

Comment: Добавил реализацию кода.